# How do I corretly use a Direct X 12 Root Signature?

Tags: c++, graphics-programming, directx12

I know a Direct X 12 Root Signature tells Direct X 12 how to use the resources between the CPU and GPU, but I'm having a hard time using it.

I tried using it before but it kept failing saying the pixel shader was not fully registered to the root signature, and I couldn't figure out why or how to fix it.

When I write a shader, how do I incorporate that shader with a root signature and should I have multiple root signatures to handle different shaders?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to define root signatures.

1. You can create the root signature C++ code, and then when you load the shader with the root signature it will 'rebuild' it to bind to that particular rootsig. This is what you'll see in most of the official samples on [DirectX-Graphics-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples).
2. You can define the root signature in HLSL. You here you use any shader blob built with that signature to create the root signature object. An example of this usage can be found in [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-GDK-Samples/tree/main/Samples/IntroGraphics/SimpleTriangle). *For Xbox console development, this is far more efficient.*

The main limitation is that ALL shaders bound at the same time must use the SAME root signature. That means you can't as easily reuse the same shader and mix & match, and will need to generate more combinations of shader blobs.

For example, in the [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12), I have to build the same shader a few times with different root signatures. For example, there are two different root signatures used in this NormalMapShader depending on if I have a specular texture or not, so I need two different builds of the same vertex shader:

```
[RootSignature(NormalMapRS)]
VSOutputPixelLightingTx VSNormalPixelLightingTx(VSInputNmTx vin)
{
    VSOutputPixelLightingTx vout;

    CommonVSOutputPixelLighting cout = ComputeCommonVSOutputPixelLighting(vin.Position, vin.Normal);
    SetCommonVSOutputParamsPixelLighting;

    vout.Diffuse = float4(1, 1, 1, DiffuseColor.a);
    vout.TexCoord = vin.TexCoord;

    return vout;
}

[RootSignature(NormalMapRSNoSpec)]
VSOutputPixelLightingTx VSNormalPixelLightingTxNoSpec(VSInputNmTx vin)
{
    return VSNormalPixelLightingTx(vin);
}
```

Another limitation is that you can't have 'unused' slots in root signatures on some older hardware. For my BasicEffect shader, I therefore have to have two different root signatures for 'textured' vs. 'untextured'.

> The *Direct3D Debug Layer* will warn when you try running 'unused slots' on these older systems, but if you aren't aware of it, this may be difficult to notice unless you do a fair amount of testing.

For examples of lots of different HLSL-defined root signatures, see [RootSig.fxh](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/blob/main/Src/Shaders/RootSig.fxh).